# How to delete SQL Consoles from Intellij IDEA Database plugin?

Tags: database, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I use Intellij 2017.3 and the database plugin to connect to SQL Server. When I need to open a console there are many of them on the list. How can I delete them? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Project Tool Window select **Scratches** view:
[image]

Since 2018.1 version scratches are located under **External Libraries**:
[image]
where you can navigate to the corresponding SQL Server data source consoles where you can view and delete not needed console files:
[image]

For convenience 2018.1.2 version will have the dedicated action **Jump to Consoles Files**. It will lead to consoles folder in
`Project view | Scratches and Consoles | Database Consoles | <folder>`
[image]

Comment: I cannot find Scratches window. Is there way to open it using hotkey?

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html#available-scratches) I should be able to select "Scratches" view using hot key Alt-F1. Unfortunately it's not available in IDEA 2018.1. So in order to delete old console I had to open it ub IDEA, then right click on tab, select `Show in file Manager` and then physically delete `.sql` file.